# django python get only the first result from a queryset?

Tags: python, django, signals, django-queryset

I am using signals to send an email to a respective user.
I am getting more than one QuerySet from my query that is:

```
orig_ordered_product = sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id)
```

and as results (becouse a have two items in this case) is:

```
<QuerySet [<OrderedProduct: Torta de Nozes>]>
<QuerySet [<OrderedProduct: Café Expresso>]>
```

Is there a way to get and do something else only with the first QuerySet as I only need the data from one of then?

I tried to use .first() and .last() but it did not work. The result of:

```
orig_ordered_product = sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id).first()
```

I get:

```
Torta de Nozes
Café Expresso
```

Thank you very much for any help os directions where to go from here!

A also tried to make a dict from the result like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=OrderedProduct)
def signals_get_old_instance_ordered_product_status(sender, instance, **kwags):
o_dict = []
try:
orig_ordered_product = sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id)
for o in orig_ordered_product:      
  if o not in o_dict:
    o_dict.append(o.status)
print(o_dict)
except:
  pass
```

but I still getting two results:

```
['orderPackaging']
['orderPackaging']
```

Shouldn't I expect to get only ony line in dict as they are the same? Because I only need one attribute from one QuerySet result not two or more.

Sure, here is my model:

```
class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
STATUS = (
('orderAwaitingPayment', 'Aguardando Pagamento'),
('orderPaid', 'Pago'),
('orderPlaced', 'Recebido'),
('orderPackaging', 'Preparando'),
('orderReady', 'Pronto'),
('ortherOnTheWay', 'a Caminho'),
('orderDelivered', 'Entregue'),
)
 order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orderedproducts')
 vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orderedproductsvendor')
 status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS, default='orderPaid')
 quantity = models.IntegerField()
 price = models.FloatField()
 amount = models.FloatField()
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.product.product_name
```

What I am suspecting is that my query is returning two QuerySets becouse it apears one line under the other. But I whish to have only one QuerySet and get only the first or last one.

Other thing that might help someone to help-me is that in Signals the instance is return more than one item (but this is expected) is there any way to get only the fist or the last item from Signals instance. That would solve my problem.

Comment: Update question with product model

Comment: Done Ahtisham. Thank you for reading my question!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```py
sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id).first()
```

Should work, and even if object does not exists it returns `None`. Be sure that you wrote the query correctly.

But you can also use:

```py
orig_ordered_product = None
try:
    orig_ordered_product = sender.objects.get(id=instance.id)
except <modelClass>.DoesNotExists:
    pass
```

`.get()` only differs from `.filter(id=...).first()` that it raises exception if the object does not exists.

Comment: Patryk, thank you for your answer but if I use .first() i get as result: the two items name but i still get two items as result and I only want to get one.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like you've managed to corrupt your database somehow. `first` should only ever return a single record! Can you check what records exist using `dbshell`?

Comment: michijnich. deshell is the manage.py shell ? Sorry but i am quite new in making queries. The query is returning two QuerySets becouse there are two items in it. But i wonder why even when i try to add it to a dict without repeating it it does repeate and keeps two iquals data.